# SQLAlchemy returns an integer

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlalchemy

I am accessing a database using SQLAlchemy. When I try to filter the table using a bunch of public and private keys I get an Attribute error saying 'int' object has no attribute 'date'.

Sometimes, I am able to filter the results once and when the filter is called again, it crashes giving me the same error. Is this the problem of SQLAlchemy or PyDev?

Below is the snippet of my filter.

```
randomize_query(session('test').query(tableName).filter(tableName.field1 == criteria, tableName.field2 == 2).order_by(desc(tableName.field3))).first()
```

The full traceback is as below

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2145, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2012, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 72, in instances
    rows = [process[0](row, None) for row in fetch]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 447, in _instance
    populate_state(state, dict_, row, isnew, only_load_props)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 301, in    populate_state
    populator(state, dict_, row)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\strategies.py", line 150, in fetch_col
    dict_[key] = row[col]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 89, in __getitem__
    return processor(self._row[index])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 250, in process
    return value.date()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Comment: What type of columns are `tableName.field1` and `tableName.field2` in your SQLAlchemy declaration for that table?

Comment: And `field1`? And can you please provide the **full** traceback?

Comment: `field1` is also an integer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: You *do* have a Date column somewhere; you are looking at the engine-specific handler for a `sqltypes.Date` column. This means that the database *result set* contains an integer where SQLAlchemy expected a a `datetime` object. It appears your database contains inconsistent values.

Comment: There is a `datetime` column in the database but it is nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown when the result set is loaded and SQLAlchemy wants to populate the result objects. One column is qualified as a `Date` type, but the Oracle result set is giving you an integer instead.

The `cx_Oracle` library will normally convert Oracle-supplied native DATE column value into Python `datetime.datetime` object. However, this is not happening for *all* your rows here.

You'll need to narrow down what row or rows have a column that is not being translated to a `datetime` object. Find a pattern in the filters that include or exclude these rows and narrow it down so you can inspect the database rows by hand in a different client.

Comment: The database modelization had problems. The type were not matched properly that led to the above error. Thank you;